# Reference for vector-valued holomorphic functions

Tags: analytic-geometry, complex-geometry

Does anyone have any reference about vector-valued holomorphic functions with information about the zeros of these functions?

Comment: Would this fall under [Several Complex Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_of_several_complex_variables#:~:text=%2C%20that%20is%2C%20n%2Dtuples,as%20a%20top%2Dlevel%20heading.)?

Comment: Zero-sets of analytic functions are the stuff of complex analytic geometry, analogous to polynomials and algebraic geometry.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.